# LOOKUP Column Value based on right-most value

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup, google-spreadsheets, search-indexing, lookup

I have a list of footage for a film that is continually changing.  They are organized in rows by REELS, and the rightmost value will be the latest version.  The first row are dates and the rest are the reels.

What I want to do is, for that latest version, to look vertically at the top row to return the DATE of that version.

I have attached an image of what I would like:

DATE of Latest Version
[image: DATE of Latest Version]

If you are not able to see the picture, try to visualize this

```
    A    B    C    D    E    F
   5/4  5/5  5/6  5/7  5/8  5/9
   1v10           1v11
        2v11           2v12  
   3v13                     3v14
```

in this case, I want to return:

```
5/7 for 1v11
5/8 for 2v12
5/9 for 3v14
```

I have used a Lookup function to figure out the latest version per Reel # horizontally, now I just need to figure out how to grab the date of that latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return the value from the header by passing the maximum column number of non-blank columns for the row in question into the column parameter of the INDEX function.

```
=INDEX($A$1:$F$1,1,MAX(COLUMN($A$1:$F$1)*N($A2:$F2<>"")))
```

[image]

If you're using O365 and have access to Lambda functions, you can use a single formula for all rows. The formula below is in cell H10 only:

```
=LET(h,$A$9:$F$9,BYROW($A$10:$F$12,LAMBDA(r,INDEX(h,1,MAX(SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(h))*N(r<>""))))))
```

[image]

Comment: This worked beautifully thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Many times the easy way is to reorder the table:

Arrange it to have the LEFTMOST value be the latest.
*(i.e. you will have to INSERT CELL <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> when you need to insert a new entry)*

By that you might not need to use a lookup function at all, or maybe VLOOKUP() will be the sane choice.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you have full capability to determine the value you seek in the row. So I'll simply address what to do from there. I'll select your secondary example of `5/9 for 3v14` for the discussion.

Not much of a discussion. You just need to know the column number. That can be found with a simple `MATCH()` function so long as there is only one occurrence of the sought value.

That can be as simple as:

```
=MATCH("3v14",HeaderRange,0)
```

where `HeaderRange" is the exact range of the column headers. A more sophisticated thought is just what to include in that range. Just the columns with the date headings? Or including the column that has the reel numbers? Actually, an even better idea for your situation is to start the range with column A, not the first two ideas, and end it with either the definite end of actual or expected data, or even go far enough past that to some column which could truly never be reached.

The reason for that is this gives you the actual ("absolute") column number, not the relative column to which you'd have to add some constant.

But what you want, for which you need the column number, is the actual value in the header range cell that heads that column. You can build that with the `MATCH()` function above as its inside element. But `XLOOKUP()` can find it directly because it subsumes `MATCH()`'s functionality into it. So:

```
=XLOOKUP(A4,  A1:Q1,  A1:Q1  )
```

There are a variety of other formulaic ways to get the contents of that cell, but they are somewhat more "compute intensive" since Excel will calculate them every time it calculates anything at all while the formula above will only recalculate if the cells in it have their value affected, or potentially affected. In Excel-speak, these functions are "volatile."

However, for a modern computer and a non-monstrous database, or non-monstrous quantity of formulas needing constant recalculation, that just isn't a problem. On my six year old bog-standard Dell desktop with 8Mb of memory, I can do a lookup on a filled 100,000 row, 30 column with barely a lag of any kind. So you might want to use such and just see what happens.

However, the above `XLOOKUP()` is simple to set up, simple to understand a year from now when someone else is using and maintaining the spreadsheet (because you got promoted), and has no volatility concerns at all. So it has some huge advantages.

Of course, if you have users who have older versions of Excel that it does not exist in, an `INDEX/MATCH` can be substituted.

Comment: In the INDEX/MATCH combo was a HUGE help thank you so much!!!